# S1.geti, S2.geti all call the same procedure (call it Sc_geti). S1.i not available. Strange chars

Tags: assembly, methods, x86, this, masm

S1.geti, S2.geti, and S3.geti all call the same procedure (call it Sc_geti). How does Sc_geti differentiate between S1.i, S2.i, and S3.i?

I can't  print S1.geti.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA 
MSG1   DB  "Message1:... ",'$'
MSG2   DB  "Message2:... ",'$'
MSG3   DB  "Message3:... ",'$'

dseg            segment byte public 'data'
_THIS       equ       es:[bx]
Sc_geti     proc      far
            mov       ax, _THIS.i   
            ret
Sc_geti     endp

Sc     struc
i      dw      ?
j      dw      ?
c      dd      ?
geti   dd      Sc_geti
Sc     ends

S1 Sc   <1,1,1,>
S2 Sc   <2,'2','2',>
S3 Sc   <'3','3','3',>
dseg            ends
;
cseg            segment byte public 'CODE'
        assume  cs:cseg, ds:dseg, es:dseg
main:   
MOV   AX,@DATA
MOV   DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG1         ;print msg1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

mov      bx, seg S1
mov      es, bx
mov      bx, offset S1

MOV   AX,@DATA
MOV   DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG1         ;print msg1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

call     S1.geti  

MOV   AX,@DATA
MOV   DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG3         ;print msg3
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H


CMP AL,13          ;ascii for "ENTER" key
JE EXIT
MOV DL,0AH         ;moving the content of AH into dl to print it
MOV AH,02          ;code to print a character
INT 21H

EXIT:
    MOV AH,4CH 
    INT 21H
END

cseg            ends
```

OUTPUT: `Message1:...Message1:...`
I try understand this document:
http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/object-oriented-programming-in-assembly/184408319 (Example 10).

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA 
MSG1   DB  "Message1:... ",'$'
MSG2   DB  "Message2:... ",'$'
MSG3   DB  "Message3:... ",'$'
MSG4   DB  "Message4: INSIDE Sc_geti ",'$'
;
cseg            segment byte public 'CODE'
        assume  cs:cseg, ds:dseg, es:dseg
_THIS       equ       es:[bx]
Sc_geti     proc      far
            mov       ax, _THIS.i
        MOV   AX,@DATA
        MOV   DS,AX
        LEA DX,MSG4         ;print msg4
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H 
        MOV DX,_THIS.i         ;moving the content 
        MOV AH,02          ;code to print a character
        INT 21H
            ret
Sc_geti     endp
cseg ends

dseg            segment byte public 'data'

Sc     struc
i      dw      ?
j      dw      ?
c      dd      ?
geti   dd      Sc_geti
Sc     ends

S1 Sc   <'1','1',1,>
S2 Sc   <2,'2','2',>
S3 Sc   <'3','3','3',>

dseg            ends

cseg            segment byte public 'CODE'
        assume  cs:cseg, ds:dseg, es:dseg

main:   
MOV   AX,@DATA
MOV   DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG1         ;print msg1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

mov      bx, seg S1
mov      es, bx
mov      bx, offset S1

MOV   AX,@DATA
MOV   DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG1         ;print msg1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

call     S1.geti  

MOV   AX,@DATA
MOV   DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG3         ;print msg3
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,4CH 
INT 21H
END

cseg            ends
```

OUTPUT: Message4 : INSIDE Sc_geti =t        v...(a lot "strange chars)

Comment: It uses `es:bx` set by the caller. Also you forgot to actually read keyboard input before the `cmp al,13`.  Nevertheless that should not give you an endless loop (which is what you get if I understood you correctly). Learn to use a debugger so you can single step the code. PS: why is your `Sc_geti` in `dseg`?

Comment: I think this is problem with _THIS       equ       es:[bx],
I change into:
`call Sc_geti` and program ran successfully.

Comment: Hmm... when I put Sc_geti to cseg i got error:
`A2017 Forward reference illegal`

in this line `geti   dd      Sc_geti`

Comment: Put the whole data segment after the code. Also you should be able to switch back and forth between segments if you like that better. I find it unlikely that changing the `_THIS` would make it work, in fact it should not even assemble then because `mov       ax, _THIS.i` would not be valid. Note that `LOOP` uses `CX` as counter you just want a `JMP`. So what exactly happens with the latest code in the question?

Comment: When I put the whole data segment after code I got severeal error: `Symbol not defined`

Comment: Now S1.geti works correctly but _THIS.i is not available. I got strange chars. Moreover I didn't get Messages from Main program.